# Firefox input ignores height on Arch Linux

Tags: css, firefox, html-input

I'm not sure whether it happens to only me or it's a bug of Firefox on Arch Linux. If I open the follow link with Firefox on Arch Linux, it alerts `32`. It alerts `18` when opened with Firefox on Windows 10.

https://jsfiddle.net/jd6088wa/28/

Browser and OS versions:

`Firefox Quantum 58.0.2 (64-bit)` on `Linux archlinux 4.15.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 10 00:00:33 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (alerts: `32`)

`Firefox Quantum 58.0.2 (64-bit)` on `Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.248)` (alerts: `18`)

It alerts `18` on all other browsers and OS's.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id='input0'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 24px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const $input0 = $('#input0');
alert($input0.height());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native input border makes the height not available in less than 32px. You have to override the default border of the input to get it working below 32px.

Set the border along with a border-radius to look nice.

```
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
const $input0 = $('#input0');
alert($input0.height());
```

```css
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id='input0'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is not ignoring the height but that's caused by box-sizing: border-box

according to Firefox

> content-box gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be added to the final rendered width.

of course the input have an additional styles (border,padding..) added by the browser which will change the given height when using box-sizing: border-box

about the difference between browsers that each one have it's style for input so the height will not be the same also this browser style changes with screen size(border width and padding)
for firefox in archlinux and windows it doesn't use the same syle

to solve that you can override the browser style

```
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 24px;
  border:2px;
  padding:2px
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s 12, not 32?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about depending on screen size?